# The Hilbert-Schmidt Theorem for Compact, Self-adjoint operators

Tags: spectral-theory, compact-operators

Suppose $T$ is a compact, self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. Then there exists an orthonormal set $\{e_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ of eigenvalues of $T$ such that every $x \in \mathcal{H}$ has a unique decomposition of the form $$ x = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_n e_n + y, $$ where $c_n \in \mathbb{C}$ and $y \in \ker(T)$.

The proof I know of the above theorem boils down to showing that $\mathcal{H} = L \oplus \ker(T)$, where $$L = \overline{\text{span}\{e_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}}.$$

I'm confused about the structure of $L$. How do we know that an element of $L$ (say $z$) looks like $$z = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_n e_n?$$ I thought that, in general, the closure of the span of an infinite set did not coincide with the set of all infinite sums of elements from that set?

Comment: I think the set of infinite sums is identical with the span of an orthonormal set

Comment: Sorry. I mean the closure of the span. Orthogonality is crucial for this.

Comment: @PeterMelech That sounds useful - do you have any idea what the sketch of the proof would be?

Comment: May be something like when $\{e_i\}$ ON then $f\in \overline{span\{e_i\}}$ implies $f=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}(f,e_i)e_i$ just as a vague idea